# Netstat Real-time TCP/IP Monitoring

Tags: netstat

Using Mac OS X's Terminal application, I want to use `netstat` to display a real-time, continuous listing of my internet connections.

For example, with Terminal open and the proper `netstat` command in use, each time I browse to a website, display the source and destination IP addresses and ports.

`netstat -w 3` displays real-time packet and byte info. I figured `netstat -w 3 -p tcp` would show actual source and destination addresses, but it does not.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you either want "tcpdump -p tcp" or "watch 'netstat -p tcp'" depending on which output you're interested in.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on `tcpdump -p tcp`? Cheers.

Comment: Oh, & `watch` too..

Comment: tcpdump -p tcp simply shows you all the tcp packets going through your default network interface, and watch runs a command repeatedly showing you the output as it changes.

Answer (score 0):

For mac or OSX, try this:

```
nettop -p 60683
```

You can also restrict the interface type, like wifi or wired...

```
nettop -t wifi -n -p 60683
```